# Why is my method undefined for type java.lang.String

Tags: java, string, counter, separator

I have a Parser class which takes in a List of strings, and prints them out line by line. I want the method `linecount()` (which does not take in any parameter) to output the number of lines in total i.e.:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Parser{
  private static List<String> lines;

  public static String parse(List<String> lines){
    return String.join(System.lineSeparator(), lines); 
  }

  public static int linecount(){
    String newString = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), lines); 
    return (newString.split("[\r\n]")).length;
  }
}
```

Such that when the List of string is given as: `List lines = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one", "two three", ""})`, calling `Parser.parse(lines)` will give you

```
one
two three
```

and thus, `Parser.parse(lines).linecount()` should output `3`. However, I came across the error `The method linecount() is undefined for the type java.lang.String`. Why is this so?

Comment: Because you need to call Parser.linecount(), not [code not shown, but probably some String].linecount(). Anyway this seems like a terrible idea, because doing it static like this will prevent your code from reusing. You should make it an object with instance variables and object methods.

Comment: `lines` would be null in `linecount()`. You need to set it in `parse` method. Second are you calling linecount on string? You have to call it on Parse. like so `Parser.linecount()`.

Comment: `Parser.parse(...)` returns a `String` and a `String` does not have the method `linecount`.

Comment: You are trying to call `linecount` on an instance of `java.lang.String`, but `linecount` is a static method in your `Parser` class... btw, your use of static here is very wrong as this has state that should be part of an instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parser.parse(lines).linecount();//<--------- Here is the problem
```

`Parser.parse()`  return a `String` and `linecount()`  is the static function of `Parser` class. Its not the function of `String` class. you cannot call in that way  `Parser.parse(lines).linecount()` and thats why it gives a error `linecount() is undefined for the type java.lang.String`. you have to call separately.

```
Parser.parse(lines);
Parser.linecount();
```

And you have to popultae `List<String> lines` Object before calling `linecount()`.

Your Regex is not Right also. Replace `"[\r\n]"` with `"[\\r | \\n]"` . Output of program is stated at the end.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Parser {

  private static List<String> lines;

  public static String parse(List<String> lines) {
    return String.join(System.lineSeparator(), lines);
  }

  public static int linecount() {
    String newString = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), lines);
    return (newString.split("[\\r | \\n]")).length;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    lines = Arrays.asList("one", "two three", "");
    lines.forEach(System.out::println);
    int count = Parser.linecount();
    System.out.println(count);
  }
}
```

**Output :**

```
one
two three

3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Parser{
  private List<String> lines;

  public String parse(List<String> lines){
    this.lines = lines;
    return String.join(System.lineSeparator(), lines); 
  }

  public int linecount(){
    String newString = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), lines); 
    return (newString.split("[\r\n]")).length;
  }
}
```

main()

```
Parser p = new Parse();
List lines = p.parse(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one", "two three", ""}));
System.out.println(lines);

System.out.println(p.linecount());
```